# Clear Directory with Salt State File

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord, saltstack

How do I clear a directory on a salt-minion using a state file? I want to delete all `*.conf` files in `/etc/supervisord/conf.d/` before I set up other supervisor services.

The following `top.sls` configuration has no effect:

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*:
  file.absent
```

`file.remove` fails as being unavailable.

Answer (score 11):

Had same issue as you. That's what worked for me.

```
remove-supervisord-confd:
   file.directory:
      - name: /etc/supervisord/conf.d/           
      - clean: True
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a perfect answer, but you could use file.absent on the directory, then recreate it.  Note that this will delete the dir every time the state is run.  You could get fancy with a jinja conditional surrounding the following:

```
supervisor-conf-delete:
  file.absent:
    - name: /etc/supervisord/conf.d

supervisor-conf-create:
  file.directory:
    - name: /etc/supervisord/conf.d
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0755
    - require:
        - file: supervisor-conf-delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cmd module in salt states. The following code could be present in your state file:

```
rm -f /etc/supervisord/conf.d/*.conf:
    cmd.run
```

You can also write more complicated commands if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, that would do it, but it doesn't feel very stateful. Any idea why the file.absent would not work? Maybe it doesn't understand wildcards. Or perhaps a `directory` module with an absent function would be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't see how "directory.absent" would be anymore stateful than a command run that has states. If you need to have a state, just introduce them in your shell script as required: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html